# Extern variable not found

Tags: c

My compiler gives the following error:"movie.c:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `Ariel_32'"

Now i have the following files, Movie.c (Witch contains the main class)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h> 
#include "Graphics.h"
#include "Fonts/Font.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;
    Color c;
    GRAP_Init();
    c.RGB = 0xB69C;
    GRAP_DrawString(20, 20, &Ariel_32, &path, c);
    return 0;
}
```

I have a subfolder named Fonts witch contains, Font.h

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_FONT_H_
#define GLOBAL_FONT_H_

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char width;            //width of this specific character
    unsigned char height;           //height of this specific character

}Size;

typedef struct
{
    Size size;                      //Actual space needed for this symbol
    unsigned char *data;            //First instance of array

}Symbol;

typedef struct
{
    Size size;                      //Maximum size that the symbols take
    unsigned char firstChar;        //first character
    unsigned char symbolSize;       //size of symbol
    unsigned char symbolCount;      //number of symbols

}FontHeader;

typedef struct
{
    FontHeader header;
    Symbol *symbols;

}Font;

extern Font Ariel_32;
#endif
```

And it contains also Ariel_32.c

```
#include "Font.h"

#define _firstChar      0x20                //First character
#define _maxWidth       0x2D                //Max width in px
#define _maxHeight      0x29                //Max height in px
#define _symbolSize     0x00F6              //Bytes needed per symbol
#define _symbolCount    0x5F                //How many symbol in this font
#define _symbolFile     "Ariel_32.sym"      //Symbol file witch contains the character data


static struct
{
    Size size;
    unsigned char data[_symbolSize];
}
const fontsym[_symbolCount] =
{
    #include _symbolFile
};

Font Ariel_32 =
{
    {{_maxWidth,_maxHeight},_firstChar,_symbolSize,_symbolCount},   //Font header
    fontsym
};
```

EDIT:
I shall also put the makefile here, since i don't have a clue about those i used someone elses. (i should really find the time too figure that part out :))

```
program_NAME := movie
program_C_SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
program_CXX_SRCS := $(wildcard *.cpp)
program_C_OBJS := ${program_C_SRCS:.c=.o}
program_CXX_OBJS := ${program_CXX_SRCS:.cpp=.o}
program_OBJS := $(program_C_OBJS) $(program_CXX_OBJS)
program_INCLUDE_DIRS := 
program_LIBRARY_DIRS := 
program_LIBRARIES :=

CPPFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))

.PHONY: all clean distclean

all: $(program_NAME)

$(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)
    $(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)

clean:
    @- $(RM) $(program_NAME)
    @- $(RM) $(program_OBJS)

distclean: clean
```

Comment: Did you link it with `Ariel_32.o`?

Comment: I think you reffer to the makefile, witch i added to my origional post.

Comment: You said `Ariel_32.c` is in a subfolder. The makefile doesn't contain any reference to the `Fonts` subfolder.

Comment: Aha, That could be it, only one small thingy, should it be added to the INCLUDE_DIRS or LIBRARY_DIRS?

Comment: program_INCLUDE_DIRS := ./Fonts
program_LIBRARY_DIRS := ./Fonts wont do the trick besides it does find the Font.h file

Comment: You need to add it to `INCLUDE_DIR`, and you need to add the files in it to `C_SRCS`

Comment: Im sorry, It won't work. I tryed some different things without result. Can you give an example of my make file?

Comment: Did you try `$(wildcard Fonts/*.c)`?

Comment: Aha, that did the trick. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `Fonts` subdirectory in the C sources variable.

```
program_C_SRCS := $(wildcard *.c) $(wildcard Fonts/*.c)
```

It will then compile the font files in the subdirectory, and link them into the program.